# How to get correctly formatted content from partly encoded text

Tags: php, html, encoding, special-characters, html-entities

My script gets large amount of texts - it may be HTML code or just plain text and special characters may be encoded or not or both.

So, the content may contain things such as:

```
Don&#039;t Do That

It's called "Meme"

He said: &#039;Yeah&#039;
```

What do I do to get it as one type - encoded or not?

I tried:

```
htmlentities(html_entity_decode($text), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"), ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8")
```

but it doesn't work in all cases. For example for:

```
•
```

returns

```
•
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried your code (with corrected parenthesis), and it returns `&rsquo; ..... &rsquo;`

Comment: It looks like some parts of the text are double encoded. That's why I get that result.

Comment: The main issue is that I get things like • instead of their codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `html_entity_decode` will not "double decode" your string, you can use something like this:

```
$str=<<<STR
Don&#039;t Do That
It's called "Meme"
He said: &#039;Yeah&#039;
STR;

$tmp=html_entity_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
while($str!=$tmp)
{
    $str=$tmp;
    $tmp=html_entity_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
}
```

Now you have a `$str` that are completely decoded, you can then encode it or directly use it, whatever you like.

Of course this is not a perfect solution -- sometimes people tends to encode their string in the first place -- it may worth a try if you can't control or filter the data source.

Comment: Perfect. That solves one problem. How about things like • ? How can I encode them? htmlentities does not seem to work. It returns trash or • itself

Comment: @GuryMax "•" is a valid character, it won't be encoded and decoded. What do you mean by "things like •"? Why is it bothering you?

Comment: I save formatted text to database and then display on HTML webpage. From time to time I can see trash instead of •, `, ‘, ” and many other. So I want to encode it properly.

Comment: @GuryMax That sounds like a _character encoding_ problem instead of _xML entity encoding_ problem. Are you sure that all data that comes _to you_ and goes _to database_ is in UTF-8?

Comment: `mb_check_encoding($txt, "UTF-8")` returns true, my MySQL database is set to utf-8-general-ci and I set charset=UTF-8 on my HTML website. Should I do anything else?

Comment: @GuryMax I don't have a clue for that...I would suggest you to collect some example of "trashed" characters and make a separated question about that. Your current title and question body aren't highlighting this point enough.